# how to delete a record related to ten tables with foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Customers table has CustomerId as a primary key.
Customers table is related to 10 other tables and CustomerId is used as a foreign key

I used the below script to delete a customer and reference in orders table

```
DELETE orders 
FROM   Customers a
       INNER JOIN CustomerId b
               ON b.CouponId = a.CouponId
```

How to delete all records related to CustomerId in all ten tables without using Delete Cascade

Comment: As far as I can tell, your `delete` should delete all rows in `orders`.

Comment: That is not valid syntax.  You don't refer to orders anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax to delete rows from joint tables:

```
DELETE t1
FROM Table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.Col_name = 'something'
```

I believe `customerId` is your column name. Looks like you have `column name`, in place of `table name`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a delete cascade you will need to manually delete the records from all related tables prior to deleting from the Customer table.